# How do you extend spring boot DataSourceAutoConfiguration.claass and DataSourceProperties.class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

How do you extend spring boot DataSourceAutoConfiguration.claass and DataSourceProperties.class?

===============================

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class DataSourceProperties implements BeanClassLoaderAware, InitializingBean {

```
private ClassLoader classLoader;

/**
 * Name of the datasource. Default to "testdb" when using an embedded database.
 */
private String name;
```

....

===============================

i need
ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
-> @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.datasource")

and

properties file in
test.datasource.username=test
-> test.datasource.username=AES256(test)

setName()
Decrypt the data

private String name in "test"

=======================================

and
How do you extend spring boot DataSourceAutoConfiguration.claass using custom DataSourceProperties.class
help!

Comment: You can disable the Spring own DataSourceAutoConfiguration and provide your own implementation of it. Did you try that? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn't extend one of Boot's auto-configuration classes. Can you describe the problem that you're trying to solve in a bit more detail?

Comment: I would like to encrypt the information about the datasource in an external file. But I would like to use SpringSource's DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class.